# D3 updating bar chart with new data set cause update issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Well the rendering of bar chart works fine with default given data. The problem occurs on the button click which should also cause the get of new data set. Updating the x-axis y-axis works well but the rendering data causes problems.

First Ill try to remove all the previously added rects and then add the new data set. But all the new rect elements gets added into wrong place, because there is no reference to old rects.

Here is the code and the redraw is in the end of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/wBNWK/9/

```
 var data = JSON.parse('[{"hour":0,"time":147},{"hour":1,"time":0},{"hour":2,"time":74},{"hour":3,"time":141},{"hour":4,"time":137},{"hour":5,"time":210},{"hour":6,"time":71},{"hour":7,"time":73},{"hour":8,"time":0},{"hour":9,"time":68},{"hour":10,"time":70},{"hour":11,"time":0},{"hour":12,"time":147},{"hour":13,"time":0},{"hour":14,"time":0},{"hour":15,"time":69},{"hour":16,"time":67},{"hour":17,"time":67},{"hour":18,"time":66},{"hour":19,"time":0},{"hour":20,"time":0},{"hour":21,"time":66},{"hour":22,"time":210},{"hour":23,"time":0}] ');

  var w = 15,
      h = 80;

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([0, w]);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
          return d.time;
      })])
      .rangeRound([5, h]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left");

  var chart = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
    .attr("height", h);

  chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i) - 0.5;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d.time) - 0.5;
    })
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.time);
    });

  chart.selectAll("text")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
      if (d.time > 10) {
        return Math.round(d.time);
      }
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "#FFF")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i) + w / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.time) - 0.5 + 10;
   });

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    function redraw() {

      // This the part where the incoming data set also changes, which means the update to x-axis y-axis, labels

      yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.time;
      })]);

      var bars = d3.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data, function (d) {
           return d.hour;
        });

      bars
         .transition()
         .duration(500)
         .attr("x", w)  // <-- Exit stage left
         .remove();

      d3.selectAll("rect") // This is actually empty
        .data(data, function (d) {
          return d.hour;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          console.log(d, d.day, xScale(d.day));

          return xScale(d.day);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return yScale(d.time);
        })
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", function (d) {
          return h - yScale(d.time);
        });
    }

    d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
      console.log('Clicked');

      redraw();
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're removing all bars and trying to add them back immediately afterwards. What do you actually want to do? Just update the positions of the bars?

Comment: Well the current example is not the best but yes I want to update the data with the new data set which means there will be more rects needed to be added. Basically if the first data set contains about 23 columns  after update there should be 31. The question is how would I append the missing rect items ?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to work if `xScale` is changed to `d3.scale.ordinal()`

Comment: Yes, could you explain why it would be easier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Sam (although there were a few more issues, like using remove() without exit(), etc.) and I am putting this out because I was playing with it as I was cleaning the code and applying the update pattern. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UjT8d/) with changes in code I made. I only changed the first few data points but this should get you going.

```
var data2 = JSON.parse('[{"hour":0,"time":153},{"hour":1,"time":10},{"hour":2,"time":35},{"hour":3,"time":150},
```

UPDATE: per request, adding logic to consider an update with new data. [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UjT8d/1/).

Comment: Well done, yes your example works and also exiting rect elements gets removed after the update. But the use case what I am missing is adding the more data points to chart, lets add two more hour parameters and then it should add more rects after update. http://jsfiddle.net/UjT8d/

Comment: For that, a few other changes are needed, such as 1) adding the enter() selection to the mix and 2) keying on the hour to help with the update. Update [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UjT8d/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're binding the same data to `bars`, the `enter` selection is empty. Once you remove the existing bars, you `append` a new bar for each data point in the `enter` selection - which again is empty. If you had different data, the bars should append.

If you haven't read through it already,  the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) is a great resource for understanding this sort of thing.